# After Revert Magento Extension Order Page Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, delete

After deleted installed extension files order page not working. My order page return Blank page.

Log Error :

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:
>   Mage_Eltrino_Diamantedesk_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Edit_Tab_Tickets'
>   in /home/giritra/public_html/app/Mage.php:595

Note : Actually i deleted Diamantedesk extension. But still error shown regard Diamantedesk extension.

How can i solve the error?

Comment: Did you cleared cache? Also related file from theme?

Comment: @SohelRana Yes, i cleared the cache and reindexed.

Comment: Reindex is not the issue, something config related issue. Check layout config inside admin theme file.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to delete **all** files of the extension. Looking the error you are reporting it seems at least this 2 files are still present in your project

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/eltrino/diamantedesk.xml
>
> app/etc/modules/Eltrino_DiamanteDesk.xml

You can find here https://github.com/eltrino/DiamanteDeskMagentoExtension all extension files